# Great difficulty in reading csv file in python

Tags: python

I am having great difficulty in reading csv file on python google collab. I have used os.getcwd() and got '/content' as the directory which I don't recognize at all. The file that I am trying to open is located in /Users/User1/Desktop/FILE.csv but no matter what method I try I still get the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/User1/Desktop/FILE.csv'
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you have to upload the file to colab

Comment: also, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The file is really large, around 17mb. Using it for a Machine learning project so its not uploading on google collab :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload your file to the colab server first, try that with:

```
from google.colab import files

upload = files.upload()
```

Then you need to use the path inside the colab container using `os.getcwd()`.